# SqliteDatabse shows empty even if elements are inserted in the database

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to use `sqlitedatabase` for entering user's name and phone number and then displaying them in a `listview`. I had no errors in inserting the details in the database but when I check the `database` if it is empty or not , it shows empty even if elements are displayed in the `listview`.

The code for `database` is given below :

**UserDatabase.java**

```
public class UserDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Table Name
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UserDataB";

    // Table columns
    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String NUMBER = "phonenumber";

    // Database Information
    static final String DB_NAME = "User_Details.DB";

    // database version
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    // Creating table query
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + NUMBER + " TEXT);";

    public UserDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseManager.java**

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    private UserDatabase dbHelper;

    private Context context;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseManager(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public DatabaseManager open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new UserDatabase(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void insert(String name, String number) {
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put(UserDatabase.NAME, name);
        contentValue.put(UserDatabase.NUMBER, number);
        database.insert(UserDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValue);
    }

    public Cursor fetch() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { UserDatabase._ID, UserDatabase.NAME, UserDatabase.NUMBER };
        Cursor cursor = database.query(UserDatabase.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db=new UserDatabase(context).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+UserDatabase.TABLE_NAME,null);
        Boolean rowExists;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            rowExists=true;
        }else {
            rowExists=false;
        }
        return rowExists;
    }

}
```

The activity in which the `listview` is populated from the `database` is given below :

**DetailsActivity.java**

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseManager manager;
    private ListView listView;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    final String[] from=new String[] {UserDatabase.NAME,UserDatabase.NUMBER};

    final int[] to=new int[] {R.id.nameDisplay,R.id.phoneDisplay};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        manager = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
        manager.open();
        Cursor cursor=manager.fetch();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
        listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailsActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = DetailsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
                final EditText name = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogEditNmID);
                final EditText phone = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogEditPhID);

                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Add Details");
                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) &&
                            !TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {

                            insertData(name.getText().toString(),phone.getText().toString());
                            Cursor cursor=manager.fetch();
                            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Empty field(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

                dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                lertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                b.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void insertData(String fname,String phnumber){
        manager.insert(fname,phnumber);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The `toast message` inside the `onClick` method of `test_button` always shows `Empty` even if there are entries in the `database`.

Can someone help?

Comment: I am not sure about this just can you try using MainActivity.this instead of Gps4Activity.this while creating DatabaseManager. My assumptin is in your case right now, the manager is existing in context of Gps4Activity so not being available in MainActivity. Since every thing looks fine, I am just guessing, so give it a shot .

Comment: Oh!! I am sorry it was a typo, actually I don't have the `MainActivity`. `Gps4Activity` is acting like the `MainActivity`. I will edit the description now

Comment: ok, @Xenolion caught your problem, look at his/her answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical error in this method

```
public boolean isEmpty().
```

If row exists why returning `isEmpty()` true?:

And if row does not exits why returning  `false` it is empty now return `true`.
So in short you returned `false` instead of `true` and `true` instead of `false`.

**So change your code to something like:**(*Read Comments for more info!*):

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
   SQLiteDatabase db;
   db=new UserDatabase(context).getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+UserDatabase.TABLE_NAME,null);

   if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return false; //because its not empty it has something thats why the cursor moved!
   }else {
        return true; //because it does not have anything and the cursor has nothing so return its really empty!
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, for solving the issue :)

Comment: Goodluck **Happy Coding!**